# Textview não mostra todo o text longo, nao quebra linha automatico

Tags: android, textview

Textview name não mostra todo text, o texto de name é dinamico, já tentei deixe ele com multiplas linhas mas não funcionou.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_description"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_address"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_description" />
    
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Da duas uma, não lembro agora, ou o componente `TextView` tem um atributo para deixar com mais de uma linha que pode ser configurado no próprio XML ou programaticamente e você vai precisar ir atrás de qual é (e também de como separar as linhas, se com `\n`, tags HTML ou de outra forma), ou existe algum outro componente mais adequado que `TextView` para a situação de textos com múltiplas linhas (talvez um seja especialização do outro).

Comment: O problema é que o texto é dinamico, pra eu ter que ir e adicionar \n. Ainda estou com o problema. não consegui resolver @Piovezan

Comment: Não sei mais como ajudar, faz tempo que não mexo com Android. Vou dar um up na pergunta e deixar aí para ver se alguém responde. Talvez o wrap_content em relação ao comprimento tenha alguma relação, talvez o ellipsize deva ser none, não sei.